# Nondecreasing function and Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is a nondecreasing real-valued function on $[c,d]$. Then $f$ is of bounded variation and is differentiable a.e. I want to prove $\int_a^b f'(x) \ dx\leq f(b)-f(a)$ for $c\leq a \leq b \leq d$.

Since $f'(x)$ is defined as $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$, I have $\int_a^b f'(x) \ dx \leq \liminf_{h\to 0} \int_a^b \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} =\liminf_{h\to 0} [1/h \int_b^{b+h} f(x) \ dx - 1/h \int_a^{a+h} f(x) \ dx]$

Clearly, $1/h \int_b^{b+h} f(x) \ dx - 1/h \int_a^{a+h} f(x) \ dx\leq f(b+h)-f(a)$ as $f$ is nondecreasing. However, when I pass $h$ to $0$, I met a problem that $f$ may not be continuous at $b$. So if I approach $b$ from the right, I might end up with something larger than $f(b)$.

Intuitively, if I want to calculate $\int_a^b f'(x) \ dx$, it should have nothing to do with the function value outside $[a,b]$. What did I do wrong in my proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say "it should have nothing to do with the function value outside $[a,b]$". Just extend $f$ to the right by $f(x) = f(b)$ for $x > b$.